# Relation between the determinants $|I+A|$ and $|I+B|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ and $B$ be nonsingular $n×n$ matrices and $I$ is the $n×n$ identity matrix, suppose $|B|$=$2|A|$. What's the relation between the  determinants $|I+A|$ and $|I+B|$? In general, if $|B|$=$k|A|$, is there a relation between the determinants $|I+A|$ and $|I+B|$? 
A weaker question is, if $|I+B|\neq 0$, can we deduce that  $|I+A|\neq 0$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=-I$ and $B=-\sqrt2 I$, with $n=2$. Then $|B|=2|A|$, $|A+I|=0$ and $|B+I|=(1-\sqrt2)^2$. There is no relation.

Answer (score 0):

For the weaker question take
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} & 1 \cr 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\quad
B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr 4 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then we have $\det(A+I)=0$ and $\det(B+I)\neq 0$.

So we cannot deduce from $\det(B)=2\det(A)$ and $\det(B+I)\neq 0$ that also $\det(A+I)\neq 0$. This hold even over $\Bbb Q$ here.

Comment: In your case, $\det(B+I)= 0$.